# DaVinci Resolve CUDA and Nvidia Server Driver not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, davinci-resolve

I've been having trouble with my Nvidia drivers since I started using Ubuntu. The Nouveau drivers are not enough, as I want to use all the power in my GPU (Nvidia RTX 3050 mobile). The reugular drivers in the "additional drivers" app do not work: when I boot, I just get a black screen. I, therefore, use the "server" drivers, which seem to work normally. However, DaVinci Resolve always gets the processing wrong with these drivers: if I open any media, I get the message "GPU processing failed". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are logging in with the xorg/non-wayland selection (little gear in lower corner when password field is active).  Check your provider setup with:

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x1ff cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

With hybrid laptop setups, the Nvidia GPU does the hard work and the Intel GPU handles the display, but these days, sometimes things get reversed (see the above), so you can change them back with environment variables, either on a per program basis or permanently in your .profile:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>
```